# Showers at/near Paris Gare du Nord station?

Tags: trains, paris, hygiene, eurostar

As part of a great skiing trip in France by train, I'll be getting a sleeper train into Gare d'Austerlitz at around 6am, then heading across Paris to Gare du Nord to get the Eurostar back to London. Given the time available for the transfer, I'm not planning to hang around at Gare d'Austerlitz, but instead catch the metro across so if there are problems there's time available to go a different way. (We got from Oxford to Bourg St Maurice without delays, in a relaxed trip, while everyone flying was delayed by a day, so karma may mean we hit problems crossing Paris...!)

If everything goes to plan though, I should have about an hour in Gare du Nord before the Eurostar checkin closes. I'm wondering if there's anywhere at/near Gare du Nord where I could get a shower? (I'll have access to the Business Premier Eurostar lounge in case that helps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [official website](http://www.gares-en-mouvement.com/fr/frpno/services-en-gare/services/#toilettes) mentions a shower facility in the main line area at the basement level, for 6EUR. I think this is the McClean facility that is mentioned in [many](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070518081007AAzZk93) [forum](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowTopic-g187147-i14-k5357780-A_shower_in_Paris_after_flying_round_the_world-Paris_Ile_de_France.html) [posts](http://www.fodors.com/community/europe/public-showers-in-paris.cfm) around the web.

The [Eurostar website](http://www.eurostar.com/FR/fr/leisure/travel_information/at_the_station/stations/paris_gare_du_nord.jsp) doesn't mention showers, even in the first class lounge.

There are [free municipal showers in Paris](http://www.paris.fr/pratique/Portal.lut?document_id=8972&document_type_id=5&page_id=5458&portlet_id=11757) (“bain-douche”) — the nearest being Les Amiraux (M<sup>o</sup> Simplon) and Meaux (M<sup>o</sup> Colonel Fabien), but you won't have enough time to go there and back.

Comment: I can confirm there are no showers in any of the Eurostar lounges (London, Paris, Brussels), I've now checked in all of them! If you bring your own towel (they tend to have only dyson style hand driers) you can manage a bit of a wash in them though

Answer (score 1):

There is a shower in the lower level at the Gare du Nord. And it does cost 6 euro. Unfortunately, it is full of these small flies and it doesn't get cleaned well. The cleaning ladies just spray water after many really dirty people wash up. It's gross. I think that the gare de Austerlitz has cleaner showers.